# Measure time taken for linux kernel from bootup to userpace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

Is there a Kernel instrumentation based way to measure the time at which the Kernel transfers over to the Userspace during boot-up ? I could use printk's with timing information, but I just wasn't sure, where exactly to place this printk, in order to observe when the Kernel transfers over to the Userspace.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?  There are many threads on the system, some in kernel space, some in user space, many transitioning from one to the other and back over time...  If you mean "when does my code start running", why not put the print at the start of your code?

Comment: By exactly I mean, the point in the kernel, where it switches to the userspace... I am unable to identify such a location, if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `start_kernel()` is called by architecture specific code (arch/architecture_type). After the  kernel loads, it calls the first user-space process,i.e. /sbin/init (or systemd on a more recent distribution) from `init_post()` Both these functions are defined in *init/main.c*.

You might want to read this [blog](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/kernel-boot-process) for a detailed description of the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

**Create your own init that logs to `/dev/kmsg` immediately**

A simpler alternative to hacking the kernel code with a `printk` is to use the following init:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/dev/kmsg", "w");
    fputs("hello init\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
    while (1)
        sleep(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

and use the kernel command line parameters:

```
init=/path/to/myinit printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y
```

Now just after the boot ends and init starts we see a message:

```
[<timestamp>] hello init
```

This is not 100% precise as you will lose some CPU cycles for the `fopen`, but I don't think it will matter much.

Minimal reproducible setup to test it out:

- https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/88cd83cd020af12b987afab5e990099f7efa2107#custom-init
- https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/88cd83cd020af12b987afab5e990099f7efa2107/kernel_module/user/init_dev_kmsg.c